# select group , count zeros

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table `users` like this:

```
id user refid
1  a    null
2  b    1
3  c    1
4  d    2
5  f    3
```

I need to select the users, grouping by id and the count number of each refid for each user  For example,

```
id    user count
1      a     2
2      b     1
3      c     1
4      d     0
5      4     0
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT u1 . id,u1 . user , count( u1.id ) count FROM users u1 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.id = u2.refid GROUP BY u1.id
```

which returns

```
id    user count
1      a     2
2      b     1
3      c     1
```

How can i have mysql return both those whose id has not been used as refid?

Comment: When I run your query, I get the last 2 rows, but the counts are 1.

Comment: yes, this is not correct

Comment: I know it's not correct, but I wonder why you said the query returned something different than it does for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM(IF(...,0,1))` to count only rows with a certain property. I think the following should work, although I am not sure, why the last two rows are missing in your output.

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.user, SUM(IF(u2.id IS NULL,0,1)) count
FROM users u1 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.id=u2.refid
GROUP BY u1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
SELECT u1 . id,u1 . user , count( u2.refid ) count FROM users u1 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.id = u2.refid GROUP BY u1.id
```

`COUNT` only counts non-null values, so you need to specify a column in `u2`, since that will be `NULL` when there's no match.

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2523/6)